# IntelliJ automatically assumes I mean Groovy class instead of Apache commons class of same name

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, import

In IntelliJ, when I type a class name like `Range` that exists in both Groovy and Apache commons, IntelliJ always assumes I mean the Groovy one, not the Apache one, even though 95% of the time it's the Apache one I need.

And when I Alt+Enter, I'm not offered a choice to import the one I want.  I always have to go to the top of the file and manually add the import.  What a drag!

Is there a way to fix this so it's not so manual and repetitive?

Answer (score 0):

You probably excluded it by accident.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked and it's not excluded.

Comment: Can you exclude the apache ones easily?

Comment: Invalidate caches or check again.

Comment: @Julian you would have to exclude groovy.lang.Range and hope for the best.  groovy.lang.* is (like java.lang) imported by default (beside some other java namespaces)